# how to train a deep learning network with different input image size?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, training-data

The input image size for a deep learning network is 224x224. I need to train the train the network with compressed images having 64x64 size without resizing them to 224x224. How can I do this using Matlab?

imageSize = [NaN NaN 3];  % '3' represents the number of color channels (e.g., RGB)

Comment: the same way you trained the 224x224 images, really

Comment: So do you have a pre-trained CNN? Are you going to fine-tune the trained model with your own data?

Comment: The network doesn't accept any input size except 224x224